# Merge 2 JSON strings in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server

I have a dimension table which has JSON column.I am using SCD Type 1 to update values in it.

```
string1={ "Name":"Suneel","Age":23,}
String2={"Name":"Suneel Kumar","Age":23,"City":"Banglore"}
```

I need JSON which is as below:

```
{"Name":"Suneel Kumar","Age":23,"City":"Banglore"}
```

Note: Since it is part of dynamic stored procedure the properties preset in the JSON may vary

```
string1={ "Name":"Suneel","Age":23,}
String2={"Name":"Suneel Kumar","Age":23,"City":"Banglore"}
```

I need JSON which is as below:

```
{"Name":"Suneel Kumar","Age":23,"City":"Banglore"}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what the logic of your "merge" is. Let's say one json string has Name, Age, and other has Name, City. Etc. Also, do you mean that strings can have any number of properties, then how do you know which property value should take precedence?

Comment: So what do you do if values are different for the same property? For example why is the result `Name":"Suneel Kumar"` and not `"Suneel"`? And are these strings stored in variables or in columns of a table?

Answer (score 0):

There is no JSON merge function in SQL Server.

You can hack it by breaking open the JSONs using `OPENJSON` and full-joining them, but it is made significantly more complicated by the fact there is no `JSON_OBJ_AGG` function.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Original o
JOIN NewData nd ON someCondition
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT '{' +
      STRING_AGG(
        CONCAT(
          '"',
          ISNULL(j2.[key], j1.[key]),
          '":',
          CASE WHEN ISNULL(j2.type, j1.type) = 2 THEN '"' END,
          CASE WHEN ISNULL(j2.type, j1.type) = 0 THEN 'null' ELSE ISNULL(j2.value, j1.value) END,
          CASE WHEN ISNULL(j2.type, j1.type) = 2 THEN '"' END
        ),
        ','
      ) + '}'
    FROM OPENJSON(o.Json) j1
    FULL JOIN OPENJSON(nd.Json) j2 ON j2.[key] = j1.[key]
) merged(Json);
```